# How to use Git pull requests when testing on feature branch

Tags: git, testing, github, merge, pull-request

We have just upgraded to the latest version of BitBucket, which allows us to disable direct pushes to the master branch. Now we are using a version of the Github Flow process (i.e. cloning feature branches from the master branch), and can only use pull requests to merge from feature/bugfix branches to the master.
We would like to perform our tests (some automated, some manual) while still working on the feature branch, and before merging onto the master branch. I was thinking of using the pull request cycle as follows:

1. issue pull request for feature
2. pull request approved by team
3. test the feature
4. after tests completed, merge to master

If we wait until after pushing to the master before testing, this might lead to bugs and regressions also being introduced onto the master.

My question is this: Since there is always the possibility that other users can merge to the master using other pull requests, this would mean that my pull request might have to be rebased to the updated state of the master if some time had elapsed after the pull request was initially opened. This means either performing the tests again, or locking the repository while at least one outstanding pull request is active. But locking the repository also has its problems, since no one else would be able to work.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: I think your assumption is wrong. Testing on pullRequest "merge commit" actually tests "feature branch merged to base branch (master in this case)", so it actually does the integration test. It does not test feature in isolation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, contention on merging to master is an issue for any team using feature branches.

Teams work fastest if they can work independently and don't have to coordinate, so locking is usually not a good solution.

The usual solution is something like this:

1. Develop the feature on its feature branch
2. Test the feature
3. Rebase the feature branch against master (or merge master into the feature branch)
4. If there were significant merge conflicts, go back to 2.
5. Merge the feature branch to master
6. Regression-test master

This workflow works best when features are small and tests are fast, so

- automate your tests as much as you possibly can. The effort will pay off. Thorough automated acceptance tests will serve both for pre-merge testing of the feature and regression testing of master.
- Plan your features so that they can be developed and merged to master in small pieces. To some extent this can be done by finding parts of a larger feature that are independently useful so can be deployed and exposed to users independently. Otherwise, develop and deploy pieces of the feature without exposing them to users until the feature is complete, using a [feature toggle](http://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html) to hide parts of the feature that would otherwise be user-visible until the feature is complete.

It will still sometimes be necessary to lock the repository for very large changes which can't be merged in pieces, such as framework upgrades.